# How can I build a Google Site Map for my PHP website?

Tags: php, xml-sitemap

I would like to build a sitemap for my newly developed website in PHP.  Can someone help me in building a sitemap for Google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google has pretty thorough documentation on the topic [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=183668)

Answer (score 1):

You could try check XML sitemap tutorial:
http://www.xml-sitemaps-generator.com/create-xml-sitemaps-with-a1-sitemap-generator/

There are lots of tools for helping you with XML sitemaps. I recommend you try out a few and find one that fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Sitemap Writer Pro](http://www.sitemapwriter.com/download.html).